# Cannot use some aggregate functions (sum or count) on Python Flink 1.11.X

Tags: python, apache-flink, pyflink

Just wanted to check if my code is wrong or this is a pyflink 1.11.X

When I try to count the number of elements in a group by query (either 'GroupBy Aggregation' or 'GroupBy Window Aggregation') pyFlink throws the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4.executeSql.
: java.lang.AssertionError: Conversion to relational algebra failed to preserve datatypes
```

If I upgrade to pyflink 1.12.X I have a workaround by casting the type to double. Surprisinglym it works with 1.12 but not with 1.11.

Can someone shad some light on this? Please find below an example to reproduce the error.

```
from pyflink.table import EnvironmentSettings, StreamTableEnvironment

# 1. create a TableEnvironment
env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance().in_streaming_mode().use_blink_planner().build()
table_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(environment_settings=env_settings)

# 2. create source Table
table_env.execute_sql("""
    CREATE TABLE datagen (
        id INT,
        data STRING
    ) WITH (
        'connector' = 'datagen',
        'fields.id.kind' = 'sequence',
        'fields.id.start' = '1',
        'fields.id.end' = '10'
    )
""")

# 3. create sink Table
table_env.execute_sql("""
    CREATE TABLE print (
        id INT,
        res INT
    ) WITH (
        'connector' = 'print'
    )
""")

# 4. query from source table and perform caculations
# create a Table from a Table API query:
source_table = table_env.from_path("datagen")
# or create a Table from a SQL query:
source_table = table_env.sql_query("SELECT id FROM datagen")

result_table = source_table.group_by("id").select("id, 1.sum as res")
table_env.create_temporary_view("output_table", result_table)

# 5. emit results via SQL query:
table_env.execute_sql("INSERT INTO print SELECT * FROM output_table").get_job_client().get_job_execution_result().result()
```